# Portable way to detect different kinds of network error

Tags: error-handling, network-programming, go

I would like to identify what kind of error occurred in the network level. The only way I found was checking the error messages with a regular expression, but now I discovered that this messages can be in different languages (depending on the OS configuration), making it difficult to detect by regular expressions. Is there a better way to do it?

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/miekg/dns"
  "net"
  "regexp"
)

func main() {
  var c dns.Client
  m := new(dns.Msg)

  m.SetQuestion("3com.br.", dns.TypeSOA)
  _, _, err := c.Exchange(m, "ns1.3com.com.:53")
  checkErr(err)

  m.SetQuestion("example.com.", dns.TypeSOA)
  _, _, err = c.Exchange(m, "idontexist.br.:53")
  checkErr(err)

  m.SetQuestion("acasadocartaocuritiba.blog.br.", dns.TypeSOA)
  _, _, err = c.Exchange(m, "ns7.storedns22.in.:53")
  checkErr(err)
}

func checkErr(err error) {
  if err == nil {
    println("Ok")
  } else if netErr, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && netErr.Timeout() {
    println("Timeout")
  } else if match, _ := regexp.MatchString(".*lookup.*", err.Error()); match {
    println("Unknown host")
  } else if match, _ := regexp.MatchString(".*connection refused.*", err.Error()); match {
    println("Connection refused")
  } else {
    println("Other error")
  }
}
```

Result:

```
$ go run neterrors.go
Timeout
Unknown host
Connection refused
```

I discover the problem when testing the system in a Windows OS with Portuguese as default language.

**[EDIT]**

I found a way to do it using the OpError. Here is the checkErr function again with the new approach. If someone has a better solution I will be very glad to known it!

```
func checkErr(err error) {
  if err == nil {
    println("Ok")
  } else if netErr, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && netErr.Timeout() {
    println("Timeout")
  } else if opError, ok := err.(*net.OpError); ok {
    if opError.Op == "dial" {
      println("Unknown host")
    } else if opError.Op == "read" {
      println("Connection refused")
    }
  }
}
```

**[EDIT2]**

Updated after seong answer.

```
func checkErr(err error) {
  if err == nil {
    println("Ok")
    return

  } else if netError, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && netError.Timeout() {
    println("Timeout")
    return
  }

  switch t := err.(type) {
  case *net.OpError:
    if t.Op == "dial" {
      println("Unknown host")
    } else if t.Op == "read" {
      println("Connection refused")
    }

  case syscall.Errno:
    if t == syscall.ECONNREFUSED {
      println("Connection refused")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: go1.6 returns `*os.SyscallError` instead of `syscall.Errno`

Comment: t.Op == "dial" can also be associated with "connection refused" with go 1.16.3 on MacOS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `net` package works closely with your OS. For OS errors, the Go std library uses the pkg `syscall`. Have a look here: http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/

The `net` package can also return `syscall.Errno` type errors.

For a simpler code in you `checkErr` function, you could consider using a type switch (http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch).

Comment: The Go `syscall` package is not portable; it's OS dependent. The Go `os` package is OS independent. ["Package syscall contains an interface to the low-level operating system primitives. The details vary depending on the underlying system"](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/)

Comment: Woops, you are absolutely right. I was looking at the wrong pkg.

Comment: I changed the answer accordingly. The `net` package can return `syscall.Errno` errors, but the details will indeed vary depending on your OS.

Comment: Great! The error returned always implements net.Error and *net.OpError structs, inside the net.OpError struct we have the internal error that can be a syscall.Errno. I still need to check the errno values returned on Windows OS for this situations. For Linux we got ECONNREFUSED for connection refused. But when we have an "unknown host" or a timeout situation there's no Errno defined (for timeout the obvious choice would be ETIMEDOUT).